# Different dput with an L in values

Tags: r

I have two different data frames and the dput for its one is:

First data frame:

```
dput(a)
structure(c(15279L, 15286L, 15293L, 15300L, 15307L, 15314L, 15321L, 
15328L, 15335L, 15342L, 15349L), class = "Date")
```

Second data frame:

```
dput(a)
structure(c(15850, 15850, 15850, 15850, 15850, 15850, 15850, 
15850, 15850, 15850, 15850, 15850,), class = "Date")
```

What is the difference between 15279L  and 15850, what is that L? Could it affect calculation? And if this different how these have same dput()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `L` you see indicates that the values are `integer`s. Consider the following:

```
a <- structure(c(15279L, 15286L, 15293L, 15300L, 15307L, 15314L, 15321L,
                 15328L, 15335L, 15342L, 15349L), class = "Date")
b <- structure(c(15850, 15850, 15850, 15850, 15850, 15850, 15850,
                 15850, 15850, 15850, 15850, 15850), class = "Date")
class(unclass(a))
# [1] "integer"
class(unclass(b))
# [1] "numeric"
```

There are definitely some differences between the two; for instance, using integers is generally more computationally efficient.